# Error running osmosis: File Not Found

Tags: osmosis

I got this error when running osmosis:

```
root@osm:/home/osm/updates# osmosis --rri workingDirectory=. --wxc ./update.osm.gz
Apr 13, 2017 10:03:34 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.45
Apr 13, 2017 10:03:35 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Preparing pipeline.
Apr 13, 2017 10:03:35 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Launching pipeline execution.
Apr 13, 2017 10:03:35 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Pipeline executing, waiting for completion.
Apr 13, 2017 10:03:37 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.ActiveTaskManager waitForCompletion
SEVERE: Thread for task 1-rri failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to read the changeset file 000/001/672.osc.gz from the server.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.downloadReplicationFile(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:135)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.download(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:264)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.runImpl(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:304)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.run(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:383)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2001)
        at java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2047)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.replication.v0_6.BaseReplicationDownloader.downloadReplicationFile(BaseReplicationDownloader.java:113)
        ... 4 more

Apr 13, 2017 10:03:37 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForCompletion(Pipeline.java:146)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

My configuration.txt :

```
# The URL of the directory containing change files.
baseUrl=http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/day/

# Defines the maximum time interval in seconds to download in a single invocation.
# Setting to 0 disables this feature.
maxInterval = 86400
```

I CAN get the same file using wget:

```
http://ftp5.gwdg.de/pub/misc/openstreetmap/planet.openstreetmap.org/replication/day/000/001/672.osc.gz
```

Behind a proxy, but this not solve:

```
export JAVACMD_OPTIONS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx.xxx.200.10 -Dhttp.proxyPort=999 -Dhttps.proxyHost=xxx.xxx.200.10 -Dhttps.proxyPort=999 -DsocksProxyHost=xxx.xxx.200.10 -DsocksProxyPort=999"
```

Some clues?